# Cannot access static html resources in a tomee-embedded application that publishes classpath as webApp

Tags: java, html, gradle, apache-tomee

I am trying to configure a `tomee-embedded` in an application. All classes and html files are in the same `gradle` project so the `tomee-embedded` serves the `classpath` as a `webApp`.

I can verify that EJB and Servlets are working and so are webservices.

However it seems that the `html` static resources that are found in /src/webapp are not served.
I cannot access for instance the index.html that is in `/src/webapp/index.html`, nor any of the other files and folders.

I have tried some approaches, like the ones shown below.

- Adding the `webapp` folder as `CustomWebResources` in the `Configuration`.
- Adding the `webapp` folder as `docBase` when deploying `classpath` as `webApp`.

  public final class Main {

  ```
  public static final void main(final String[] args) {

   final Configuration configuration=new Configuration();

   //Attempt one, does not work
   configuration.addCustomWebResources("webapp");
   configuration.setHttpPort(8082);
   try (final Container container = new Container(configuration)) {

       //Attempt two, does not work either
       final File docbase=new File("webapp");
       System.out.println("Docbase:"+docbase.getAbsolutePath());
       container.deployClasspathAsWebApp("/",docbase);
       System.out.println("Started on http://localhost:" + container.getConfiguration().getHttpPort());

       container.await();
   } catch (final Exception exception) {
       LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception));
   }
  ```

  }
  }

For reasons of completeness the gradle import I use is the following:

```
  implementation 'org.apache.tomee:tomee-embedded:8.0.6'
```

How can I tell the `tomee-embedded` to also serve the `index.html` and the other resources under `src/webapp` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out.
The following will work when running with the "run" task of the gradle application plugin.

```
   public final class Main {

   public static final void main(final String[] args) {
    
    final Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
    configuration.setHttpPort(8082);
    try (final Container container = new Container(configuration)) {

        //Works in gradle application:run
        final File docbase=new File("src/main/webapp");
        System.out.println("Docbase:"+docbase.getAbsolutePath());
        container.deployClasspathAsWebApp("/",docbase,true);
        System.out.println("Started on http://localhost:" + container.getConfiguration().getHttpPort());

        container.await();
    } catch (final Exception exception) {
        LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception));
    }
    }
    }
```

The docbase should point to the exact location of the webapp folder.
This means that in an actual implementation distribution the relative `src/main/webapp` should be replaced by the actual webapp folder location.